# Graviton fluctuation suppressed in large $N$ matters

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, approximations, large-n

I have a question about semiclassical gravity approximation.

For probing Hawking radiation, we usually treat gravitational theory as semiclassical assuming large $N$ matters. However, I do not know the reasons why we can drop quantum fluctuations of gravitational mode in large $N$ limit.